# Vala varargspassing property: value pairs

Tags: variadic-functions, vala

In the Project Vala Tutorial at [Variable-Length Argument Lists](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Variable-Length_Argument_Lists), there is a calling technique shown:

> A common pattern with varargs is to expect alternating string - value pairs as arguments, usually meaning gobject property - value. In this case you can write property: value instead, e.g.:
> actor.animate (AnimationMode.EASE_OUT_BOUNCE, 3000, x: 100.0, y: 200.0, rotation_angle_z: 500.0, opacity: 0);
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> actor.animate (AnimationMode.EASE_OUT_BOUNCE, 3000, "x", 100.0, "y", 200.0, "rotation-angle-z", 500.0, "opacity", 0);

How can I decode that? The code shown in the article is for the more normal all commas parameter passing. It doesn't properly decode the alternate style.

I tried the example code given:

```
void method_with_varargs(int fixed, ...) {
    var l = va_list();
    while (true) {
        string? key = l.arg();
        if (key == null) {
            break;  // end of the list
        }
        double val = l.arg();
        stdout.printf("%s: %g\n", key, val);
    }
}
```

And it prints

```
x: 0

rotation_angle_z: 0
```

If I take out the double val

```
void method_with_varargs(int fixed, ...) {
    var l = va_list();
    while (true) {
        string? key = l.arg();
        if (key == null) {
            break;  // end of the list
        }
        stdout.printf("%s: \n", key);
    }
}
```

it prints

```
x:0

y:0
rotation_angle_z: 0
opacity: 0
```

My guess is that this needs to be a different type than string, but what?

```
string? key = l.arg();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to be sure without you showing the exact function call, but my guess is that you're mixing an int into the caller side.  `0` is not the same as `0.0`; the former is an int, the latter is a double.  Typically, ints are 32 bits and doubles are 64 bits, so if you pass an int but try to read it as a double (or vice versa) things have a habit of getting out of sync and corrupting not just the current argument but future arguments as well.

Basically, either make sure all your value arguments are the same type, or assign the values of different keys to a variable of the right type (i.e., `if (key == "opacity") { uint val = l.arg(); } else { double val = l.arg(); }`).

With functions like `Clutter.Actor.animate()`, the type is determined by looking up the relevant GObject property.  [x](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-1.0/Clutter.Actor.x), [y](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-1.0/Clutter.Actor.y), and [rotation-angle-z](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-1.0/Clutter.Actor.rotation_angle_z) are all floats, and [opacity](http://valadoc.org/#!api=clutter-1.0/Clutter.Actor.opacity) is an uint.  Floats get promoted to double when passed to variadic functions (I can't actually remember if C specifies this or it's just all the x86 calling conventions) which is why `0.0` works as expected, but it would probably be more correct to use `0.0f` for float arguments and `0.0` for doubles.

When using variadic arguments (in both C and Vala) you have to keep in mind that *you lose type-safety*.  You have to be very careful about what types you're passing, because the compiler can't tell you when you mess up.

Comment: The exact function call was included (and is cut and pasted from the tutorial) is this:         `actor.animate (AnimationMode.EASE_OUT_BOUNCE, 3000, x: 100.0, y: 200.0, rotation_angle_z: 500.0, opacity: 0);`

Comment: If it helps - I added a counter, and it picks this up as 4 parameters: `x: 100.0, y: 200.0, rotation_angle_z: 500.0, opacity: 0` , and all I get this the beginning string. Everything starting with the ':' is lost.

Comment: Here, I created a gist, this should explain better. There are two classes Actor1 is the standard style, and, Actor2 uses the colon separated style that I am asking how to decode: [Varargs.vala](https://gist.github.com/darkoverlordofdata/6ad7694a07a9332a04d0)

Comment: Apparently this is/was a bug in Vala 0.28. On a lark, I swapped the 2 print statements, and them the alternate syntax started working, and the standard syntax failed. I observed that I was using 0.28 (I installed this version because it was required by Valama). I switched back to 0.30, and the issue went away, I'm good.